# Why can't I use import/export in node.js enviroment?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm working in my first node.js app coming from a vue/laravel background where I alsways used import/exports, now I'm trying to use it in my node.js but I get the following error:

```
(node:13072) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\app.js:7
import MapsService from '../services/MapsService';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I thought node.js was pretty common, how can I not use import/exports? This is what I have in my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
//process.env.DB_HOST
require('dotenv').config()


import MapsService from '../services/MapsService';

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {

    MapsService.scrapeAddress();

    res.send('Hello World!');
});


app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

And in my MapsService file I use imports/exports too, does that mean I will have to use this require thing I see? How can I transform my MapsService file to be require friendly?

```
//import { Client } from '@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js';
import * as geometry from 'spherical-geometry-js';
import axios from "axios";
//const axios = require('axios').default ??;
import VenuesService from '../services/VenuesService';


export class MapsService {

   



}
```

Comment: You will have to use require, unless you use a bundler like webpack for your nodejs app.

Comment: Well, the warning says it all `To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension`. Did you try it ?